# How to write service layer stress test with TestNG?

Tags: multithreading, unit-testing, hibernate, testng, stress-testing

I need to write a stress test for my service layer. I started doing that with Unitils, JUnit4 and JUnitPerf, but had no luck. That is why I decided to try TestNG, but I have problem with session closing and transactions when trying to run test in multi-threaded mode.

I am using the following framework stack: Spring, Hibernate, TestNG, Unitils

I need a non-transactional multi-threaded test. The test will call service layer methods. Each call will start new transaction. So there are several threads which simultaneously start several transactions each.

So the test should be something like this:

```
public class ServiceStressTest extends UnitilsTestNG 
  @SpringBeanByType
  private MyService myService;

    @DataSet
    @Test
    public void createTestData() {
    }

    @Test(invocationCount = 100, threadPoolSize = 50, dependsOnMethods = "createTestData")
    public void test1() throws Exception {
      myService.method1(); // Starts new transaction and commit it.
      myService.method2(); // Starts new transaction and commit it.
    }
}
```

And the service looks like the following:

```
...
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
...
@Transactional
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {
    public void method1(){
         sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(smth); (update/delete)
    }
    public void method2(){
         sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(smth); (update/delete)
    }
}
```

If I set *threadPoolSize* to 1 everything works fine. But whenever I change it to be multi-threaded I get exception which says that the session was closed.

Answer (score 0):

Is this all the code we need to know about? It sounds like you might have a @BeforeMethod or @AfterMethod that closes the session.

Or this is done by one of the other annotations that I'm not familiar with (@Transactional maybe?).

Comment: I wonder why session and new transaction is not opened on each service call